# Allocator error in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

Suddenly, a wierd error started to come up in my console saying

More than 2048 allocators are registered. Reduce the allocator count.

This error leads to freezing of editor.

Comment: Please walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem, so that we can help you diagnose it and test potential solutions.

Comment: What version (exactly) of Unity are you using? I am asking because the only mention I can find about "More than 2048 Allocators are registered" is in [the changelog of 2020.1.0a21](https://unity3d.com/unity/alpha/2020.1.0a21).

Comment: Unity 2019.3.0 is the version.

Comment: I also researched a bit and found it under bug fixes section of unity 2020's changelog.

Comment: I think its a bug.

Comment: @DMGregory Okay then, what should i do now.

Comment: It sounds like you found a solution: use a version that does not have this bug.

Comment: Why are you using 2019.3.0? The latest version in the 2019.3 branch is 2019.3.15f1. You can also upgrade to 2019.4.1f1. Don't be afraid to upgrade to the newest version of the Editor regularly.